# BUILD FAILED: Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseMainManifest'

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-v1

We upgraded the SDK Version:31, as per the google' new requirements. Now building the application is causing an error.

> Task :app:processReleaseMainManifest FAILED
> ~/platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml Error:
> Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.
> ~/platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml Error:
> Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.

Answer (score 0):

I also have an Ionic-v1 project, I suffered a lot, but I migrated to SDK 33.

This helped me a lot: https://ionic.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/7891143965975-Migrating-to-Cordova-Android-11

Good luck!